# How do I examine the first character of a QString?

Tags: c++, qt

I want the following code to remove a leading zero from a price (0.00 should be cut to .00)

```
QString price1 = "0.00";
if( price1.at( 0 ) == "0" ) price1.remove( 0 );
```

This gives me the following error: "error: conversion from ‘const char [2]’ to ‘QChar’ is ambiguous"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue is that Qt is seeing `"0"` as a null-terminated ASCII string, hence the compiler message about `const char[2]`.

Also, `QString::remove()` takes two arguments. So you code should be:

```
if( price1.at( 0 ) == '0' ) price1.remove( 0, 1 );
```

This builds and runs on my system (Qt 4.7.3, VS2005).

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
price1.at( 0 ) == '0' ?
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the 'at' function returns a `QChar` which is an object that can't be compared to the native char/string "0".  You have a few choices, but I'll just put two here:

```
if( price1.at(0).toAscii() == '0')
```

or

```
if( price1.at(0).digitValue() == 0)
```

`digitValue` returns -1 if the char is not a digit.

Comment: It should probably be `price1.at(0).digitValue()`.

Comment: Since `QChar::QChar(char)` seems to be non-explicit, just `...at(0) == '0'` should do it, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString s("foobar");
if (s[0]=="f") {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> QChar QString::front() const Returns the first character in the
>   string. Same as at(0).
>
> This function is provided for STL compatibility.
>
> Warning: Calling this function on an empty string constitutes
>   undefined behavior.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#front

```
QString s("foobar");

/* If string is not empty or null, check to see if the first character equals f */
if (!s.isEmpty() && s.front()=="f") {
    return;
}
```